# Long list of Artists

Tags: navigation, homepage

I am in the process of learning AngularJS, and thought to myself let me build a really simple, very common website using Angular and ASP.NET Web API.

The website I want to build is a lyrics website, but I do want it to be very user friendly and intuitive to use. You've all seen the current status of lyrics websites on the internet, they are just so dull :/ Or at least the one that come on the first page on Google.

What would you say is the best homepage for this sort of thing? I want the user to feel absorbed in the content, I want him/her to "feel" how they should navigate to the next song or artist.

I have something like this, what are your thoughts, I always find it difficult coming up with UX solutions when I have a LOT of data (in this case Artists). **What are my options when wanting to make long lists of data visible, and at the same time easy to navigate?**

[image: Lyrics website]

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank You.

Comment: IT's not really that clear what your question is here. Do you just want us to give you a review of your UI? (because that's not really what a Q&A site is about). Can you specify the actual question you have a bit clearer so we can give you a definitive answer.

Comment: Apologies @JonW. Is that any better?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fear "long lists of data" will never be particularly usable. You already have a search box in your proposal, and that will serve anyone who has a specific interest. Just make sure it accepts artists, albums, song titles, lyrics, in perfect spelling as well as with errors. Present the results in a structured way, since there are so many categories.

As for the rest of the homepage, I guess it should be an invitation to explore. Apart from a good visual design (based on the album covers? - since these are recognizable and have already been designed to a good extent), I'd expect to see most recent additions, most viewed, most liked, featured, random (the last two per decade or style?), even requested ones or some needing more work (think of wikipedia). If you have users with accounts, add their favorites, their requests, etc.

That is to say, refrain from adding a long list, and this applies to "reduced long lists" such as starting letters or publication years as well. Besides being dull, they also add to loading time.

Answer (score 1):

*Warning: Lots of music video links in the content. Grab my playlist! :)*

### Searching?

Music is something that **can not** get searched *non emotionally*. When you are trying to tackle this from a technical perspective

> Which fields in the dataset should be filterable?

the you are already on the wrong route. The question you will ask yourself always is

> What is my current mood?

and sometimes even

> In what mood do I want to be right now?

so forget the idea of searching *facts* about tracks.

### Explore!

When you are talking to (good) DJs or music collectors (or both in one person), then you will see a completely different view. To people interested in music, the music composed and produced by [Tricky](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lWIeVTs94rI) will be closely related to [Aphex Twin](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7MBaEEODzU0), David Bowie and [Trent Reznor](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gPVrFIP0CMs). The simple fact is that their take on music is related - something that you can't add as a tag, a category or otherwise.

And while I would love to find [Kelis](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N3JFwd1bk4Q), [Dead Prez](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4jNyr6BJZuI) or [Lords of Brooklyn](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qY1T14Faz90) in the same search results, someone else would want to stumble upon [Sister of Mercy](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=evu3I0ZoERc) or maybe on *(urgh)* ... Genesis <sup>No way that I link that</sup>. Technically Sisters of Mercy could be stuffed together with Genesis, but honestly, I would rather kill someone for that attempt than to listen to it a second time. Again, that's a "false true" as it fits technically (by ~type, used instruments or time being published), but never ever for someone who can not see both together.

### A network ... graph?

I could imagine a dozen fitting UIs, starting from a network graph to a list of related artists that one can up/downvote (or dismiss completely), but there is one thing that every UI has in common:

> Music is personal. Let a user decide what is related.

The only thing important for you is to let your system remember a users selection, but distinguish between "not in the mood for that" and "urgh! not in my face!".

### What about tech?

Initially you won't have any results at all - with what I described above. And that is where the "weight" of hard facts still will come into play, but it should decrease over time, when the user matures in your systems and the system will be defined by him. As a starting point [Anna F.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W_vR5u5QxZY) is in the same "genre" as [Lilly Allen](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sy-Ifv-nzQk). Later on, maybe [Fat Freddys Drop](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eCJg63SziL4) or [Kate Nash](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ryH5cga0yUI) will take over and be closer related.

[image]

<sup>If you understand the reason why there is a cassette and a pencil in that picture, then you will understand the answer for sure.</sup>